# Simplest function that creates swapped dictionary there values should be tuples with all corresponding keys

Tags: python, collections

I wrote a function that changes values and keys between each other. But I'm required to make it **simpler** using just **one loop "FOR"**

***IF - ELSE not allowed***

```
def swap_dict(d):
    swapped_dict = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        if value in swapped_dict:
            swapped_dict[value].append(key)
        else:
            swapped_dict[value] = [key]

    for key in swapped_dict.keys():
        swapped_dict[key] = tuple(swapped_dict[key])

    return swapped_dict


print(swap_dict({1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 4, 7: 2, 9: 4}))
```

```
def swap_dict(d):
    swapped_dict = {}
    for key, val in d.items():
        swapped_dict.setdefault(val, set()).add(key)

    for key in swapped_dict.keys():
        swapped_dict[key] = tuple(swapped_dict[key])
    return swapped_dict

print(swap_dict({1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 4, 7: 2, 9: 4}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one loop inefficiently by recreating the `tuple` value each time the same key comes up:

```py
def swap_dict(d):
    swapped_dict = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        swapped_dict[value] = swapped_dict.get(value, tuple()) + (key,)
    return swapped_dict
```

**Update:** used the `get()` method to replace `if/else`

Comment: I got a review that I can't use "if-else". Instead, i need to combine the two loops:

Comment: `for key, val in d.items():
        swapped_dict.setdefault(val, set()).add(key)` and second from main post

Comment: And does this create the tuples you are after?

Comment: separated from each other, they work fine. but I have no idea how to combine them

Comment: Сan’t thank you enough!  Unfortunately I don't quite understand how that part works `+ (key,)`

Comment: It turns out that `tuple()`s can be added together, So, while `tuple()` is an empty tuple, `(key,)` is the syntax for a tuple of one item, so that can be added to either an empty tuple, or a tuple of one or more items that is currently stored under `key`.

Comment: You just made my day because half of it I was trying to figure out the code!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to look for all keys having the value you're looking for, so that you do not need the second `for` loop to map from lists to tuples.

```
def swap_dict(d):
    swapped_dict = {}
    for value in set(d.values()):
        swapped_dict[value] = tuple([k for k,v in d.items() if v==value])

    return swapped_dict


print(swap_dict({1: 2, 3: 4, 5: 4, 7: 2, 9: 4}))
```

Still, list comprehension is a sort of for loop, I don't think you can avoid it.

Comment: You could make this more efficient by looping: `for value in set(d.values()):` Also doing that makes your `if/else` redundant.

Comment: Big-O-wise this is a severe downgrade. The nested loops mean it is O(n**2), whereas the original is O(n).

Comment: i'm updated the topic with comments from review